# How to monitor Fileaccess in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file, ntfs

i want to detect changes in filesystem for a special directory and i heard that is possible to monitor the file-access. Can anyone tell me how to monitor a directory for example in C#.NET?

THX
Rene

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the `FileSystemWatcher`.

Full documentation on MSDN is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: with FileSystemWatcher class you can monitor create/update/delete/rename operations only, we cant use this class to track file access.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`FileSystemWatcher` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).

As far as I know this does not work on Novell Network shares (at least the last time I tried it, some years ago).